# How to build a simple JavaScript to-do list with localStorage

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple JavaScript to-do list with DOM methods and am attempting to implement `localStorage` for the list items. `localStorage` appears to function properly when items are both added and removed. However, the word `undefined` is thrown to the screen before the list items are rendered. Any idea why this is happening? Much appreciated!

JS:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myUl");

function add() {
  var item = document.getElementById("newItem").value;
  var itemTxt = document.createTextNode(item);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  var btnx = document.createTextNode("x");
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "remove()");
  btn.appendChild(btnx);
  li.appendChild(itemTxt);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function remove() {
  var task = this.event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(task);
}

ul.innerHTML = localStorage["list"];

setInterval(function(){
  localStorage["list"] = ul.innerHTML;
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
  <input id="newItem" />
  <button onclick="add()">add</button>
  <ul id="myUl">New List</ul>
```

Comment: You're using `ul.innerHTML = localStorage["list"];` before `localStorage.list` has been populated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated code with comments:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myUl");

function add() {
  var item = document.getElementById("newItem").value;
  var itemTxt = document.createTextNode(item);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  var btnx = document.createTextNode("x");
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "remove()");
  btn.appendChild(btnx);
  li.appendChild(itemTxt);
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  localStorage["list"] = ul.innerHTML // updating localstorage
}

function remove() {
  var task = this.event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(task);
  localStorage["list"] = ul.innerHTML // updating localstorage
}

if (localStorage["list"]) { // checking, if there is something in localstorage
  ul.innerHTML = localStorage["list"];
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQpwpz

**NB**: It is not a best practice to put `html` into `localStorage`, but I believe you know it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I checked the demo, but it looks like "undefined" still shows up. Any idea how to set this code up to remove that?

Comment: I did post answer, but then find an error in demo. Most likely `undefined` was saved into `localStarage` before the code was fixed. try to clean `localStorage` in browser and refresh a page (or use incognito mode in Chrome).